# Can the Selmer curve be viewed as an elliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

A famous counterexample to the Hasse principle is the Selmer curve, with equation $$C: 3X^3+4Y^3+5Z^3=0,$$ which has a local point everywhere but no $\mathbb{Q}$-points.

Since an elliptic curve over a base field $k$ is defined to be a genus one smooth projective curve with a distinguished $k$-rational point, I'm wondering is it true that if $C$ has a $k$-point for some number field $k$, then $C/k$ is an elliptic curve? Is it then possible to write $C$ in Weierstrass form, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Of course. Try it yourself with an example of the number field you get by adjoining the cube roots of 3,4 and -5. In that case your elliptic curve becomes $ x^3 + y^3 = z^3 $ which can be put into Weierstrass form rather easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example you can adjoin an algebraic element $\alpha$ which is a root of $3X^3 + 4$ to $\mathbb Q$ to get a number field $k$, upon which this curve obtains a rational point $P = [\alpha:1:0]$. You can then follow the procedure in example 2.1 of this [document](https://trac.sagemath.org/raw-attachment/ticket/3416/cubic_to_weierstrass_documentation.pdf) to make a change of variables to turn the above equation into one in Weierstrass form. In this case, we get the affine equation $y^2 + 720y = x^3 -172800$ which, over $k$, ends up acquiring a rational point and thus is an elliptic curve.

If you are lazy like me, you can also ask Sage to do it for you as [in here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwdjL0KgzAYAHch7_Dh5E-QlthJ41LSRSjiKioxTWggUglVEp--ocstd9zBbQIxBwcezjhFUVvU3Gxv3gCF574u0j60NK-EZHwikEMZmr6oHfb4bGg7jChStA_aTSQvMx94y86JhKwLi-E_w3DFcBkrFDHKjNHbV4v7bg85K_tZZ7EvWiQKd2nFflDhKRg=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: Thank you for including the handy software, I'll have a look.